# snprintf and sprintf explanation

Tags: c, string-formatting, printf

Can someone explain the output of this simple program?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char charArray[1024] = "";
    char charArrayAgain[1024] = "";
    int number;

    number = 2;

    sprintf(charArray, "%d", number);

    printf("charArray : %s\n", charArray);

    snprintf(charArrayAgain, 1, "%d", number);
    printf("charArrayAgain : %s\n", charArrayAgain);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
./a.out 
charArray : 2
charArrayAgain : // Why isn't there a 2 here?
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Because snprintf needs space for the \0 terminator of the string. So if you tell it the buffer is 1 byte long, then there's no space for the '2'.

Try with `snprintf(charArrayAgain, 2, "%d", number);`

Comment: How about instead of `2`, you do `sizeof(charArrayAgain)`.

Comment: agreed, sizeof(charArrayAgain) would be better - although often you have a pointer rather than an array, in which case sizeof() isn't going to work.

Answer (score 6):

```
snprintf(charArrayAgain, 1, "%d", number);
//                       ^
```

You're specifying your maximum buffer size to be one byte. However, to store a single digit in a string, you must have *two* bytes (one for the digit, and one for the null terminator.)

Answer (score 4):

You've told `snprintf` to only print a single character into the array, which is not enough to hold the string-converted number (that's one character) and the string terminator \0, which is a second character, so snprintf is not able to store the string into the buffer you've given it.

Answer (score 4):

The second argument to `snprintf` is the maximum number of bytes to be written to the array (`charArrayAgain`).  It includes the terminating `'\0'`, so with size of 1 it's not going to write an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

Check the return value from the snprintf() it will probably be 2.